# Core 2.0 missing Scaffolding items

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a Core 2.0 project with User Base Authentication, but upon looking at the default AccountController only the Logout() action method was generated.

Where are the other scaffold items like Register(), ForgotPassword(), ExternalLogin(), etc...

However, I can register users just fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Core2.Data;

namespace Core2.Controllers
{

  [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
  public class AccountController : Controller
  {
     private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
     private readonly ILogger _logger;

     public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger)
     {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
     }

     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
     {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have created a [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio) ASP.NET Core MVC Application:

> Razor Pages is a new feature of ASP.NET Core MVC that makes coding page-focused scenarios easier and more productive.

If you look in the `Pages` folder within your project, you will see a Razor Pages based implementation of the relevant user authentication actions:

```text
Pages
- Account
  - Login.cshtml
  - Login.cshtml.cs
  - Register.cshtml
  - Register.cshtml.cs
  - ...
```

The latest Visual Studio 2017 defaults to creating a Razor Pages application when using ASP.NET Core 2.0, as is shown below:

[image]

If you want the traditional MVC approach, you can select the `Web Application (Model-View-Controller)` option instead, which will generated the controllers, actions, etc, that you expected.